# How to add properties to child components using React.cloneElement?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

[Note: CodeSandbox is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-black-sbxk7?file=/src/App.tsx)]

I am trying to implement a `ToggleButtonGroup` which "selects" a button when clicked. Only one button can be selected at a time.

[image]

The usage should be as follows, where clicking on any of the buttons, sends an `onChange` event to the parent with the button's value:

```
export default function App() {
  const [color, setColor] = useState<string | undefined>();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ToggleButtonGroup value={color} onChange={setColor}>
        <ToggleButton value="R">Red</ToggleButton>
        <ToggleButton value="G">Green</ToggleButton>
        <ToggleButton value="B">Blue</ToggleButton>
      </ToggleButtonGroup>

      <h4>Color: {color}</h4>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I understand that the standard way to do this is to add properties to the child components (in this case `ToggleButton`) using `React.cloneElement()`. Here's my attempt to do this, but it is not working:

```
interface ToggleButtonProps {
  value: string;
  selected?: boolean;
  children: ReactNode;
}

const ToggleButton = ({ selected, children }: ToggleButtonProps) => {
  return <button className={selected ? "selected" : ""}>{children}</button>;
};

interface ToggleButtonGroupProps {
  value: string | undefined;
  children: ReactNode;
  onChange: (value: string) => void;
}

const ToggleButtonGroup = ({
  value,
  children,
  onChange
}: ToggleButtonGroupProps) => {
  const buttons = React.Children.map(children, (child) => {
    React.cloneElement(child, {
      selected: child.props.value === value,
      onClick: () => {
        onChange(child.props.value);
      }
    });
  });

  return <div>{buttons}</div>;
};
```

The cloned `ToggleButton`s are not even rendering!

1. What am I doing wrong? How do I make this work?
2. There are a couple of TypeScript errors in `ToggleButtonGroup`. How do I fix them?

My CodeSandbox is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-black-sbxk7?file=/src/App.tsx).

Comment: Your function must return the newly created react elements. Add ``return`` in front of ``React.cloneElement(...`` or remove the curly braces from the anonymous function.

Comment: Good catch! Added `return` in front of `React.cloneElement()`. The buttons are now showing up, but the selection is still not working.

Comment: As a matter of fact, the `onClick()` function injected from `ToggleButtonGroup` is not even being called!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

Add `onClick` to `ToggleButton` component:

```
// ---------- ToggleButton ----------
interface ToggleButtonProps {
  value: string;
  selected?: boolean;
  children: ReactNode;
  onClick: () => void;
}

const ToggleButton = ({ selected, children, onClick }: ToggleButtonProps) => {
  return <button onClick={onClick} className={selected ? "selected" : ""}>{children}</button>;
};
```

**Alternative solution**

However, I usually find that it's never worth it to mess with JSDom nodes.

For your particular case I would suggest passing props for your ButtonGroup directly and let ButtonGroup render the list.

Using Omit so I won't have to pass `selected` and `onClick` as they will be set by ButtonGroup.

```
interface ToggleButtonGroupProps {
  value: string;
  options: Omit<ToggleButtonProps, "selected" | "onClick">[];
  onChange: (newValue: string) => void;
}

const ToggleButtonGroup: React.FC<ToggleButtonGroupProps> = (props) => (
  <div className="toggle-button-group">
    {props.options.map((option) => (
      <ToggleButton
        key={option.label}
        value={option.value}
        onClick={() => props.onChange(option.value)}
        label={option.label}
        selected={option.value === props.value}
      />
    ))}
  </div>
);
```

Full example on [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/hidden-paper-dwvvy)

Comment: Love the alternate answer - so much simpler! Thank you so much, Oleksandr.